# Botões posicionados no rodapé da página sobem quando o teclado dos dispositivos móveis aparece

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

Estou desenvolvendo uma página responsiva que possui no inicio um campo de busca e no rodapé dois botões com posicionamento absoluto, em dispositivos móveis após clicar no input o teclado é exibido e empurra os botões para cima, existe alguma forma de impedir isto? Como fazer os botões se manterem fixos?

Comment: Poderia [edit] a pergunta elaborando um [mcve]?

Comment: Já tentou com `position: fixed;` ?

Comment: segue a url: http://staging.newcore.com.br/passoponto

Comment: fixed tem o mesmo comportamento que o absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere/adicione os estilos da `div .principal` para:

```
.principal{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}
```

E da `div` dos botões:

```
div.footer-buttons{
    bottom: 0;
}
```

E coloque a `div` dos botões (`div.footer-buttons`) no final da `div .principal`, já que os botões são apenas links e não usam o `form`.

**O que essas alterações irão fazer?**

Irá definir uma altura mínima na `div .principal` de `400px` e os botões ficarão sempre no `bottom` da `div`, de modo que quando o teclado aparecer e a tela ficar menor que `400px` de altura, os botões não subirão.

---

**Forma alternativa via jQuery:**

Com este método você não irá precisar fazer as alterações de CSS acima. O código irá ocultar os botões caso a tela fique muito curta para cabê-los (ao abrir o teclado no dispositivo, boa parte da altura da tela é ocupada pelo teclado) e irá mostrá-los novamente quando houver espaço (ao fechar o teclado). Basta adicionar o código:

```
<script>
$(window).on("resize", function(){
  if(window.innerHeight < $("a.btn.btn-success.btn-lg.green-button").offset().top+120){
     $("div.footer-buttons").hide();
  }else{
     $("div.footer-buttons").show();
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: valeu dvd, ambas funcionaram!